# Rails 3 - Split JSON output into chunks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, caching, split

I have an application that pulls data (between 100,000 and 10,000,000 records) from a MongoDB via JSON and displays them to the user.

Due to the fact that the JSON responsive has around 35MB at the moment (will get MUCH bigger), I tried to cache the function that pulls the data (which works out nicely performance-wise) via

`caches_page :pull_data`

but once the cache is regenerated, it (naturally) takes up a lot of time to pull and process the data again. Is there a way to split up this huge JSON response into chunks to make this easier or is there generally a better solution to deal with such a situation?